# Cast a pointer to point to main function in C

Tags: c++, c, pointers, casting, int

Hi i see an example of pointer as below:

```
void main()
{
    int a=197,*p=&a;
    (int(*)())p==main;
}
```

I do not know what the statement `(int(*)())p==main` do ?

Comment: It doesn't do anything useful, and accomlishes absolutely nothing, whatsoever. Wherever you found that example, it does not seem to be a very good resource for learning C++.

Comment: Please specify if this question is asking for C or C++. They are different language.

Comment: Your title doesn't really reflect the actual question you ask.

Comment: `void main()` is not valid C++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Comment: A function pointer to `main` isn't all that useful in C++. The C++ Standard states [The function `main` shall not be used within a program](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#3). My language lawyering is weak, so I'm not sure if that extends to holding a pointer to `main`, but having a pointer to `main` suggests that sooner or later someone is going to use that pointer to `main`, and after that [Crom only knows what's going to happen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we split it up into smaller parts we have

- `(int(*)())p`
- `==`
- `main`

The first is a cast of `p` to a pointer taking either an indeterminate number of arguments (in C) or no arguments (in C++).

It compares this pointers to the pointer that `main` decays to.

Then throws away the boolean result (the result is not used).

Note that there is a very big semantic difference between C and C++ here.

Comment: the (int(*)()) make me confuse with this statement. Why don't they just use (int*) to cast pointer to point to int variable ?

Comment: @TiếnThànhNguyễn Because a pointer to a function doesn't have to be the same as any other pointer.

Answer (score 3):

> I do not know what the statement (int(*)())p==main do ?

`int(*)()` is a type. It is pointer to a function that returns int and takes no arguments.

`(T)expr` This is an explicit conversion i.e. a cast. The result of the right hand expression is converted to the type in parentheses. `(int(*)())expr` converts the right hand expression to a pointer to function.

In `(int(*)())p` the converted expression is `p`. `p` is a variable of type pointer to int. Since the original pointer did not point to a function, the resulting value is arbitrary as far as the C++ standard is concerned.

`(int(*)())p==main` compares the converted pointer to the address of the `main` function. The result of the comparison is discarded.

---

P.S. You've declared that `main` returns `void`. This is not allowed in C++. Furthermore, as a consequence, the pointer to function `main` does not match with the pointer type `int(*)()`. To fix this, declare `main` to return `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`==` is a compare operator. You're comparing the pointer to the `main()` function with the pointer to the variable a. But you're not using the comparison, for example in an `if` statement, so that line doesn't really do anything.